# How to play video and show seekbar which put in the Azure storage and the file is large?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5-video, azure-storage

I put a video which is over 2 GB in Azure storage and play by URL which generate by Azure.

```
<video controls autoplay width="738" height="420" style="max-width:100%;height:auto">
    <source src="AzureStorageURL/XXX.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I have two questions:

1. It takes a long time to show on the web page, how to make it faster?
2. When it loads on the page, the seekbar doesn't work in Chrome but it's fine in IE and Edge.

I can't jump to any time that I want, even the time ever played.

Comment: Is there any free video player whcih can embedded in html, that can add header or play large video?

Comment: The `<video>` tag itself is a video player. What (type of) header are you asking about exactly? **(1)** _"It takes a long time"_ this can happen if the video metadata is placed at back of MP4 bytes (coming last) but video won't play without metadata since you must wait for all 2GB bytes to download before getting metadata.

Comment: @VC.One Yes, seek for another tag or component. I use <video> now, but it play when the video load completed. Is there any way to play video and load together?

Comment: _"Is there any way to play video and load together?"_ That sounds like metadata issue. Share the file link with us, or you can **check** yourself by downloading [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20) which is a **hex editor** (it shows you the file bytes). If you open the MP4 you should see `ftyp` in first line then before reaching next 3 or 4 more lines, you should see `moov` or `mdat` text. If you see `mdat` first, then you have **media data** and the **movie metadata** (which is `moov`) is at back (don't bother to scroll to near bottom to see, we now know problem).

Comment: **PS**: Just to check, you are not using any scripts like PHP to get the MP4 into video tag, right? So now confirm if you see `mdat` first (or give me the video link to check. You can delete that comment later) . If you see **mdat** then next step is to get a program to fix the file. I can show you how to fix using FFmpeg (do you use it already)?

Comment: @VC.One Thanks you very much, I solve the question by add the parameter like "?sv=2020-04-08&st=2021-12-07T06%3A17%3A13Z&se=2200-12-08T06%3A17%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=rl&sig=" after the video url

Comment: Seems the parameter make azure storage give back the video through the status code 206.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239943/discussion-between--and-vc-one).